# pixi.stage.width and pixi.stage.height take a scaling factor at the beginning, but take concrete pixel values on later usage

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

**What I try to achieve:**
To resize a renderer and container according to the limits of an HTML element without care if the result gets distorted or not.

**What my problem is:**
I use the *resize* function to set *pixi.stage.width* and *pixi.stage.height* to the HTML element's *clientWidth* and *clientHeight*, and also resize the *pixi.renderer* to the HTML element's dimension.

Upon loading the page, I only see a blue canvas, but when I change the window size it works as intended.

I found out that the reason for this is, that *pixi.stage.width* and *pixi.stage.height* take a scaling factor in the first execution of *resize*, but upon a resize via a *window.onresize* they take concrete pixel values.

**What my goal is:**
I don't care if I have to put in the pixel values or have to calculate a factor, but I would like to use one method for resizing the renderer and stage the first time and one every resize.

**That is how my current code looks:**

```
import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js'

const mainNode = document.getElementById('main')

const pixi = new PIXI.Application({
  resolution: window.devicePixelRatio || 1,
  antialias: true,
  autoDensity: true,
  roundPixels: true
})

const background = PIXI.Sprite.from('./images/gate_tag.jpg')
pixi.stage.addChild(background)

mainNode.appendChild(pixi.view)

resize(pixi)

window.onresize = () => {
  resize(pixi)
}

export function resize(pixi) {
  pixi.stage.width = mainNode.clientWidth
  pixi.stage.height = mainNode.clientHeight

  pixi.renderer.resize(mainNode.clientWidth, mainNode.clientHeight)
}
```